# How do I add elements horizontally instead of vertically in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, separator, pysimplegui

I'm trying to get my GUI to have 2 "parts" (one left and one right), and naturally, adding elements to the layout just expands it vertically, so I tried doing a "left_part" layout and a "right_part" layout, then merge them with a Horizontal Separator padding, but it gives me something entirely different.

Ideally, I would want something like this (maybe with a thin line in between too):

[image]

What I get is this:
[image]

This is the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

left_part = [

    [sg.Text("Pick your favorite fruit")],
    [sg.Input(size=(25, 1), key="path")],
    [sg.FileBrowse(key="fav"), sg.Button("Submit")],
    [sg.Image(key="img1")],

    [sg.Text("Pick your favorite number")],
    [sg.Input(key="num", size=(10,10))],
    [sg.Button("Submit")],

]

right_part = [
    [sg.Text("Pick your favorite animal")],
    [sg.Input(key="animal")],
    [sg.Button("Show image of animal")],
    [sg.Image(key="img2")]
]

layout = [
    [left_part],
    [sg.HSeparator(pad=(500,0))],
    [right_part],
]

window = sg.Window("Favorites", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layout in following form `left`, `separator` and `right` vertically or in rows.

```py
layout = [
    [element1],
    [sg.HSeparator(pad=(500,0))],
    [element2],
]
```

Should be like this

```py
layout = [
    [element1, sg.HSeparator(pad=(500,0)), element2],
]
```

Since the element1 and element2 are for another complex layout, use Frame or Column element.

For horizontal layout, Instead of `HSeparator`, `VSeparator` will be used here.

For elements in Column vertical aligned top, so option  `vertical_alignment='top'` added.

So the `layout` in your code maybe like this,

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Column(left_part, vertical_alignment='top'), sg.VSeparator(), sg.Column(right_part, vertical_alignment='top')],
]
```

[image]